# Getting Run Part of code that creates SparkContext or GlueContext on worker nodes to achieve parallelism

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

**I'm trying to run following code with PySpark :**

```
# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
   StructField("id", StringType(), True),
   StructField("type", StringType(), True),
   StructField("name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("end_time", StringType(), True),
   StructField("pass_fail", StringType(), True),
   StructField("location", StringType(), True),
])

# Sample data
data = [
("467", "Glue", "xyz", "2020-02-08 14:02:41.123635", "2020-02-08 18:17:58.82756", "Succeeded",
 "s3://my-bucket/staging/odp/SO/customer/ODP_SO_CUSTOMER_202070719.csv"),
("235", "Glue", "xyz", "2020-02-08 14:02:41.123635", "2020-02-08 18:17:58.82756", "Succeeded",
 "s3://my-bucket/staging/odp/BO/venodr/ODP_BO_VENDOR_202070719.csv"),
]

# Create a DataFrame
valid_records_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

# Filter DataFrame to get only "Passed" records
passed_records_df = valid_records_df.filter(valid_records_df["pass_fail"] == "Succeeded")

# Extract distinct system values
distinct_systems = passed_records_df.select("location").distinct()

# Define the processing logic
def process_row(row):
   project_name = 'odp'
   release_timestamp = '2020-02-12'
   file_name = row['location'].split('/')[-1]
   input_path = row['location']
   file_type = row['location'].split('/')[6]
   system = row['location'].split('/')[5]
   output_path = f"s3://my-bucket/raw/{project_name}/cleaned/{system}/{release_timestamp}/{file_type}/{file_name}"

   # Script generated for node S3 bucket
   S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": ";"},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            input_path
        ],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
   )


    # Script generated for node Amazon Redshift
    redshift_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="redshift",
    connection_options={
        "sampleQuery": query,
        "redshiftTmpDir": f"{tempDir}",
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "connectionName": "my_connection",
    },
    transformation_ctx="redshift_df",
   )

   redshift_data_df = redshift_df.toDF()

   mapping = [redshift_data_df.rdd.collect()[0][col] for col in redshift_data_df.columns]

   print(file_type, output_path)
   print(mapping)
```

> Now, Apply the logic to each system in parallel using foreach

**distinct_systems.foreach(lambda row: process_row(row))**

**While running the above code it is failing with the error :**

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears
> that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast
> variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on
> the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information,
> see SPARK-5063.

I know, it's failing as I've used GlueContext within the code, my task is to run the process_row() function for each location record available in the dataframe.
I want to peroform some more spark datframe operations within the process_row() function.

Can someone please help me with the solution on how should I approach this issue and make this code run in parallel across the workers. And it'd be great if you can share some insights on this issue as well.

Comment: Can't you use an UDF function and pass that function to your dataframe?

Comment: Wonder if you have solved the issue? I'm having a similar confusion.